# Send notification on the phone based on ajax response

Tags: cordova, notifications

I build an app in PhoneGap Build and I need help.
My app must send a notification into status bar of the phone.
What my app do ? When users is close to specific location ,the app will send a notification to phone(in status bar/notification tray).
like

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=215oh&s=8#.U8fm2TSSyMI]

With watchposition I send ajax request with current position .If current position is on 5- metter to my destination my response will be 1 .
If response 1 I need to send the notification.The problem is that I don't know how to send the notification.

Can anyone help me?
PS:I work on phonegapbuild.
PS:I need for ANdroid for the moment but if you know a method that will work on the both platforms is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Cordova plugin for Local Notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications). I use it in cordova built projects and it works great. It claims to be supported in Phonegap Build as well, but I didn't try this myself.